# How can I use npm to download and update modules from a list in a package.json file?

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I am using windows with node.js downloaded. I created this package.json.

```
{
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "name": "abc",
    "devDependencies": {
        "del": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.2",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.2.8",
        "gulp-typescript": "^2.3.0",
        "less-plugin-clean-css": "^1.2.0",
        "typescript": "^1.3.0"
    }
}
```

Is there an npm command line task that I can run to fetch all of these modules and install / update these into a node_modules directory?  If needed I can change my package.json so I would appreciate advice on that also.

Thanks

Comment: 'node install' would do it. You run it in the same directory as the package.json.

Comment: Thanks. I was think it should be npm install. Will node install work with the package.json format I gave? How about updating to the latestt packages?

Comment: It should work with the format you have. Here is a little package.json cheat sheet i use often: http://browsenpm.org/package.json

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't 
   "npm install"
do the trick? (from your folder that contains the package.json)

It works on linux, haven't a window machine to try right now

Answer (score 0):

try

```
npm install
npm update --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already had the package.json file (with dependencies entries), then you can use npm install to install dependencies on node_modules directory.

> npm install

or you can update the dependencies to use latest version (will override currently installed dependencies on node_modules directory) using npm update

> npm update

You don't have to put the dependency you want manually to package.json, you just use command npm install {package-name} with additional option like --save / --save-dev / --save-optional.

In example you want to add dependency of node-q to your application, you can do this:

> npm install q --save

Juggling into different option `--save`-prefixed value will act as follows,

- `--save` will add dependency to dependencies attribute of your package.json, it will be installed mainly for your application
- `--save-dev` will add dependency to devDependencies attribute of your package.json, it will be installed for development phase of your application (usually it is testing dependencies)
- `--save-optional` will installed for optional (nice to have) dependencies. I rarely used it for my applications or libraries anyway.

Don't forget you MUST run commands from your application directory (the one that node_modules directory resides).